# Error connecting GCP Cloud Sql with GCP App Engine

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm getting error in connecting GCP cloud sql with GCP App Engine. Its working fine in locally using google auth proxy but when deploy app using **gcloud app deploy** and after successful deploy getting error on server

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT at Connection._handleTimeoutError (/layers/google.nodejs.yarn/yarn_modules/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:205:17) at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17) at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) 
 {
 errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
 code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
 syscall: 'connect',
 fatal: true
 },
```

getting above error in the below code

```
const Sequilize = require("sequelize").Sequelize;
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();


const sequilize = new Sequilize(
  process.env.DB_NAME,
  process.env.DB_USER,
  process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST, //db host public ip
    dialect: "mysql",
    socketPath: process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION, //`/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME`,
  }
);

module.exports = { sequilize };
```

app.yml code

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

runtime_config:
  operating_system: "ubuntu22"
  runtime_version: "18"

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: /cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `host` and instead use `socketPath`.

App Engine will run the Cloud SQL Proxy for you and make a Unix socket connected to your instance available at `/cloudsql/<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>`.

For more info, see https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard#node.js.

```js
const sequilize = new Sequilize(
  process.env.DB_NAME,
  process.env.DB_USER,
  process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  {
    dialect: "mysql",
    socketPath: process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION, //`/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME`,
  }
);
```

Comment: I am using sequelize to connect database so how can I  use unix socket as well?

Comment: Updated my answer to make that clear.